# nginx load balancing keep redirect me wrong

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, nginx, load-balancing

hi i have nginx server and other webserver which i want to hide from public direct access. but when i try to access that server on root i send redirect response to client to url like this: server/test/spring/main. when i try to access it from nginx server i get the server url redirect instead nginx url.

example:

my-nginx.com
my-server.com

if i want to access myserver.com/test/spring/main from nginx server i guess i have to access my-nginx.com/test/spring/main but when i do that i get redirect to url myserver.com...

my config:

```
upstream my-server {
    server my-server.com;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name my-nginx;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://my-server/;
   }
}
```

the other think is when i access the root page on my-server.com i redirect the client to "https://my-server.com/test/spring/main".

Why i'm redirect from my-nginx.com url to my-server.com?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration seems do not have big problem, and I also use proxy_pass to access other domain in our production environment, and do not redirect.

You should be care of the last '/' in "`http://my-server/`", usint "`http://my-server`" instead, or just using "`http://my-server.com`" with no upstream.

The behavior with '/' or with not '/' is a little different.